# Where can I find the meanings of MSDN library icons?

Tags: c#, .net, msdn

[alt text http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/sdk15ce5.pubmethod(en-us,VS.90).gif](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/sdk15ce5.pubmethod(en-us,VS.90).gif) method.

[alt text http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/sdk15ce5.CFW(en-us,VS.90).gif](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/sdk15ce5.CFW(en-us,VS.90).gif) what does this mean?

[alt text http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/t69yczb0.static(en-us,VS.90).gif](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/t69yczb0.static(en-us,VS.90).gif) static.

and there are lot more symbols. Where can I get the reference of all these?

**EDIT:**

Just in case anybody also want here is a meaningful link

http://tinyurl.com/msdnicons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list is [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe.aspx) You can also use [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_members.aspx) to see how it fits into a library.

Comment: awesome!! I've been googling with some keywords, but couldn't find it. 
I actually don't know what are the appropriate keywords. :P

Comment: "meaning of msdn library icons" is what I used. Got a forum post that had these links. (basically just used your title)

Comment: That list only covers the things shown in VS, not all of the other icons used in the MSDN library.

Comment: You can also just rest the mouse cursor above the icons, and a tooltip will appear (at least inside Document Explorer).